# -0の存在について

Tags: c++, c

float型については-0が存在すると思いますが、なぜ存在するのかわかりません。
何かに利用されたりinfやNanのようにエラーとして扱うものですか

Answer (score 9):

0に符号があることのメリットは、[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#924)で幾つか言及されています。

> When a multiplication or division involves a signed zero, the usual sign rules apply in computing the sign of the answer. Thus 3·(+0) = +0, and +0/-3 = -0. If zero did not have a sign, then the relation 1/(1/x) = x would fail to hold when x = ±∞. The reason is that 1/-∞ and 1/+∞ both result in 0, and 1/0 results in +∞, the sign information having been lost. One way to restore the identity 1/(1/x) = x is to only have one kind of infinity, however that would result in the disastrous consequence of losing the sign of an overflowed quantity.

一番理解しやすいのは「乗除算において符号が維持されること」でしょうか。同様の理由で、無限大にも`+Inf`と`-Inf`が存在します。

他には、logのように0近傍で不連続かつアンダーフローが生じる数学関数や、複素数演算で`-0`が役立ちます（と同ドキュメントには書いてありました）。

---

> If a distinction were made when comparing +0 and -0, simple tests like if (x = 0) would have very unpredictable behavior, depending on the sign of x. Thus the IEEE standard defines comparison so that +0 = -0, rather than -0 < +0.
>   [...]
>   Although distinguishing between +0 and -0 has advantages, it can occasionally be confusing. For example, signed zero destroys the relation x = y ⇔ 1/x = 1/y, which is false when x = +0 and y = -0. However, the IEEE committee decided that the advantages of utilizing the sign of zero outweighed the disadvantages.

`+0`と`-0`の2種類が存在することのデメリットもあります。浮動小数点数同士の比較では`+0`と`-0`は区別されず、`+0 == -0`となります。一方で、`x == y`と`1/x == 1/y`は同値(⇔)でなくなってしまいます（`1/+0 != 1/-0`つまり`+Inf != -Inf`）。

Answer (score 2):

符号が数値表現（仮数部）とは別に存在するためですかね。
（整数型においても１の補数や符号と絶対値表現などの場合に－０、＋０の二種類の０が生じる）

ウィキペディアの[－０](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%88%920)が参考になるかもしれません。
普通にはエラーではなく普通に０として扱えるはず。